# loop through map object and modify xml using xsl transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, dictionary

I have a xml and Map object  ,map contains some additional info about xml nodes ie.

```
<searchPersonResponse>
 <persons>
   <person>
     <id>123</id>
   </person>
   <person>
     <id>456</id>
   </person>
  </persons>
</searchPersonResponse>
```

and my map is something like this-

```
infoMap<123, <name="abc"><age="25">>
infoMap<456, <name="xyz"><age="80">>
```

and the ouput I want is like this :-

```
<searchPersonResponse>
 <persons>
  <person>
   <id>123</id>
   <name>abc</name>
   <age>25</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <id>456</id>
    <name>xyz</name>
    <age>80</age>
   </person>
 </persons>
</searchPersonResponse>
```

I  searched a lot fot this kind of eample/sample , but didnt find a similar one. please help !! thanks in advance

Comment: Where the map come from? It is stored as a string? Can be changed into XML?

Comment: xml comes from a 'sql query' or 'object deserialization' and map comes  from another  business call. it cab be changed to xml also .

Comment: So, it could be possible to put the map (in XML format) and the XML in the same file?

Comment: yes, but again I am not goodat xslt transformation

Comment: I have posted a solution, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are able to put everything in the same XML file, you can build the following XML file containing the map information and data.

```
<xml>
    <!-- Original XML -->
    <searchPersonResponse>
        <persons>
            <person>
                <id>123</id>
            </person>
            <person>
                <id>456</id>
            </person>
        </persons>
    </searchPersonResponse>
    <!-- Map definition -->
    <map>
        <value id="123">
            <name>abc</name>
            <age>25</age>
        </value>
        <value id="456">
            <name>xyz</name>
            <age>80</age>
        </value>
    </map>
</xml>
```

And now you can use this stylesheet to transform the XML file to the desired output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template : copy all elements and attributes by default -->
    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Avoid copying the root element -->
    <xsl:template match="xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="searchPersonResponse" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
        <!-- Copy the person node -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Save id into a variable to avoid losing the reference -->
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="id" />
            <!-- Copy attributes and children from the person element and the elements from the map-->
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|*|/xml/map/value[@id = $id]/*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```